# disallowed key characters on server

Tags: codeigniter, url

Below is my error
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyyp8.png)

This is my config:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-,()/@=+?&';
```

This is my input file in system folder.

**Below is the code**

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }

    // Clean UTF-8 if supported
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

I tried all options still i am getting disallowed characters only on server.

Comment: When you added the new characters did you restart server.

Comment: i restarted now, but it is the same issue.
please help me here

Comment: in your function to clean input keys you did not add = character in your preg_match  function .according to your url .is that helpful?

Comment: Thank you, i tried with = in input file, it didt support me.

Comment: try adding =, ? and & character if you are passing with you custom function